# What do you call a note that gives preliminary information before the main part?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a single word (if not, a natural phrase) for a note that you write before starting the main article/part/question etc.

It can give preliminary information (in general). However, it can be a mild warning (but I would like to avoid calling it a "warning" which is too strong) or a reminder (thus, we can call it a "reminder" but I want a more general word).

An example context would be, when you are posting a question on stackexchange sites, you put a note in advance that people read it before the question and you make them think twice before posting an answer, you remind them that the question is (not) about this or that etc.

For example:

> _____: This question is not only about finding a single word. I would like to get a detailed answer that addresses all the related questions.
>
> << Main question... >>

---

I considered the word *note* itself but I want to distinguish it from the notes that you write after or during the main part.

Then, *advance note<sup>1</sup>* came to my mind as a phrase but it also has another meaning and can be confused with *advance notice*.

*Prenote<sup>2</sup>* could be a nice word but it does not sound that natural and dictionaries list it as a verb only.

There are of course words like *preface* and *prologue* but they are usually too formal and comes before longer written works like novels.

*Caveat<sup>3</sup>* is similar to *warning* but it might give special instructions. Can it be the word I'm looking for? I might have seen it used in this way on EL&U but it is used in law also.

<sub>I might be over-thinking and the answer might be very simple but I wanted to give as much information as I can. You might also talk about differences between words that fit to similar settings.</sub>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> a draft on owners or agents of a ship drawn by the master for the benefit of a sailor usually for one month's advance wages [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advance%20note)</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *trans.* To note or mention previously. [OED]</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> an explanation or warning that should be remembered when you are doing or thinking about something [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caveat)</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure why *preface* is objectionable- while it can be used before longer works it doesn't have to be and is often used more informally in conversation as in: "I'd like to preface this by saying..."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A suitable word for your brief introduction is ***preamble***. It's not as formal as *preface,* and can be as short as a sentence (which would be unusual for a preface). *Preamble* can be countable or a mass noun, as Oxford Dictionaries shows:

> 1. A preliminary or preparatory statement; an introduction:
>      *he could tell that what she said was by way of a preamble*
>      *I gave him the bad news without preamble*
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preamble)

It's pronounced as three syllables, and does have the same root as *amble* — medieval Latin *praeambulum,* from late Latin *praeambulus* **'going before'.**

Comment: It looks like this was the only word I didn't mention. Do you think it fits to the example context I gave?

Comment: @ermanen Yes; that's why I suggested it :-) I've amended the answer to make that clear.

Comment: Is it actually common to *write* the word "preamble" as a subheading? I have a feeling it's more common in speech than in writing. E.g. "Before I start my presentation, I need to make a short preamble" I ask because I find it slightly jarring in this [post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229982/what-is-happening-to-thank-you).

Comment: It seems to me that Americans, at least the more civic-minded among us, upon hearing the word *preamble*, are liable to think of [the preamble to the Constitution of the United States](https://constitutioncenter.org/interactive-constitution/preamble), often referred to as just “the preamble.” Which is, ya know, a fairly formal document. So I’m not sure *preamble* will necessarily carry a “not as formal” sense for some readers.

Answer (score 10):

I'd usually use **Preface** in this sense, and I'd argue it's most common.

There's also **Precis**, though I think that it's more commonly used to describe a sort of brief preliminary synopsis.

Answer (score 8):

*NB*: Maybe something might be interesting to note well.

Comment: [Nota bene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene) is an Italian and Latin phrase meaning "note well". -Had to Google that one.

Comment: N.B., NB, and Note well and excellent choices. They can be used at any point in the text where the author feels it will call special attention to the particular words. Traditionally, the Latin initials were common, but as the above comment shows, avoiding Latin and simply writing "Note well:..." in English will likely be more useful for your audience. There are some narrow genres, however, in which N.B. is mandated in specific situations.

Comment: Funny is how many people think that _N.B._ means _note below_. As if English was ever the world's first language :p

Comment: I like this better than my own suggestion of "preface" - it fits the question better, I feel, at least for a brief preliminary aside.

Answer (score 3):

If we forget about Stack Exchange (for a moment) and everything after the first two paragraphs, *abstract* fits nicely.

**Abstract** (summary) -[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_%28summary%29)

> An abstract is a brief summary of a research article, thesis, review, conference proceeding or any in-depth analysis of a particular subject or discipline, and is often used to help the reader quickly ascertain the paper's purpose. When used, **an abstract always appears at the beginning** of a manuscript or typescript, acting as the point-of-entry for any given academic paper or patent application.

Answer (score 0):

**Preempt**
pre·empt, prēˈempt/ verb

> 1. take action in order to prevent (an anticipated event) from happening; forestall
> 2. acquire or appropriate (something) in advance -[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursive&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=preempted&spell=1)

A preamble is simply something said before hand. A preemption offers an introductory caveat. Also, *prompt* might fit where appropriate.

Comment: But _preempt_ doesn't fit as a noun.

Comment: @ermanen *Preemptive note* does. I could also say, "since you preempted the question with..." or a *preemptive preamble*. Or just revert to [caveat](https://www.google.com/search?q=caveat&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), which is perfect: a warning or proviso of specific stipulations, conditions, or limitations.

Comment: On SE, it seems more likely to find caveats at the end of a post, usually in tacked-on edits. IMO, preambles only appear in the dissemination of knowledge, not in questions, those have caveats.

Answer (score 0):

A very well-known word that has this meaning is “[introduction](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Introduction)”.

TFD gives:

> 1. The act or process of introducing or the state of being introduced.
> 2. A means, such as a personal letter, of presenting one person to another.
> 3. Something recently introduced; an innovation: "He loathed a fork; it is a modern introduction which has still scarcely reached common
>    people" (D.H. Lawrence).
> 4. Something spoken, written, or otherwise presented in beginning or introducing something, especially: a. A preface, as to a book. b.
>    Music A short preliminary passage in a larger movement or work. c. A
>    basic introductory text or course of study.