# Polite Answers to "What else can I do for you? "

Tags: politeness, conversation

Suppose that I call a company's call center for help.
And near the end of the conversation, the staff asks a question like "what else can I do for you ?".

How can I give a polite answer to this sort of question if that was the only problem I had and it is now solved so I need no more help ?

Can I say "that's it for now" ?

Comment: I usually just say (using more-or-less standard American English) "No, thanks" or "No thanks, that's it."

Comment: I usually ask if they'll wash my car.  Jokingly, of course, then I say "Thank you, no."

Comment: Nope. All's well.

Answer (score 3):

That's it for now.

That's all for now.

(You can even throw in a 'thank you' or a 'thanks', [in order to save those phrases from disappearing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229982/what-is-happening-to-thank-you). I was being sarcastic, but in truth you can include them.

Nothing else, thank you. (Here the 'thank you' is encouraged, else the 'nothing else' could seem too abrupt.)

Not now, thank you (very much). (Added after OP's comment.)

You can add 'Have a super day' or 'Have a great day' if you want. These specific terms may only be appropriate in American English, I'm not for certain.

Comment: Can I say "not now, thank you very much." ?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can.

Comment: How about "No thanks", "No, thank you sir", or "That'll be it. Thank you"?